# Frequency histogram on condition variable = X in R

Tags: r, histogram

I've got a data frame called X in R, columns A through I.

I want to generate a frequency histogram for all records that have col A = "London" and col B = 10, and the histogram will be based on that record's value in col E, which can take on ten values. In the histogram, I want each column to note the number of occurrences for each possible outcome of col E, if that's possible.

Could someone advise? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
X <- data.frame(colA = sample(c("London", "Manchester", "Chelsea"), 50, T), 
                colB = sample(8:11, 50, T), 
                colE = sample(1:5, 50, T))

#> X[X$colA =="London" & X$colB == 10,]
#     colA colB colE
#3  London   10    3
#7  London   10    1
#35 London   10    3
#36 London   10    3
#42 London   10    5

hist(X[X$colA =="London" & X$colB == 10,]$colE)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
X_subset <- subset(X, select = Delay, subset = A == "LONDON" & B == 10, drop = TRUE)

hist(X_subset)
```